# Symfony3 Controller loading time

Tags: symfony

I have a question.
Where could be a problem when my controller loading speed is sometime 1800ms?
[image]

Here is controller code:

[image]

Is here some way to write this code better?

Thanks

Comment: Hi kironet, It is only one function of your controller which sets so much time? Clear cache ? You used Assetic Bundle ?

Comment: Yes, my whole project is right now just that function. Cache is cleared, and yes I'm using assetic.
Sometime loading time is +- 188ms, but sometime higher then 3***ms
My hosting is A2Hosting Turbo.

Comment: Are you using your code as dev (so incl full logging, debug mode etc.) or as prod?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, by experience since the version 3 of symfony, Assetic slow considerably considerably the time of load of a page in environment of "dev".
I think that that your problem comes from the Assetic bundle..

**I propose an alternative solution :**

Deactivate "Assetic" and pass by other alternative solutions: https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/index.html

Or return to the simple include of the files js/css/img/... with the 'asset' function twig `{{ asset('js/script.js') }}`

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, also save the getRepository instance in some variable, good practice and will reduce speed but not enough.

Answer (score 0):

> Is here some way to write this code better?

It's not the source of your problem.

**For me cache configuration was the key to solve such a problem.**

php.ini settings (win)

```
 zend_extension=php_opcache.dll

 opcache.memory_consumption=128
 opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8
 opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
 opcache.revalidate_freq=0
 opcache.fast_shutdown=1
 opcache.enable_cli=1

 realpath_cache_size = 4096k
```